# Linq to Entities orderby parent table value. (MVC)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a Member table which has a foreign key from ASPNETUSERS table.  My ASPNETUSERS table has additional fields in it for First Name and Last Name which I would like to use as sort values in my Members Controller.

```
 var members = from m in db.Members.Include(m => m.AspNetUser).Include(m => m.Location) select m;
```

This is currently the initial query i am retrieving to get me all the members and searching is easy as i can use the following syntax.

```
 members = members.Where(m => m.AspNetUser.LastName.Contains(searchString)
 || m.AspNetUser.HomePhone.Contains(searchString)
 || m.AspNetUser.MobilePhone.Contains(searchString)
 || m.AspNetUser.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
 || m.IdentificationNumber.Contains(searchString));
```

However when i try to do my sorting e.g.

```
 members = members.OrderByDescending(m => m.AspNetUser.LastName);
```

It "works" however it doesn't actually sort but the Last name of the related table.

Can someone advise me as to what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

**Update: Below is full Action Result Method.**

```
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string Command)
    {
        //Redirect back to login page if not authenticated
        if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

        ViewBag.LastNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lastname_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm = sortOrder == "firstname" ? "firstname_desc" : "firstname";

        var members = from m in db.Members.Include(m => m.AspNetUser).Include(m => m.Location) select m;

        if (Command == "Search")
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                members = members.Where(m => m.AspNetUser.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                       || m.AspNetUser.HomePhone.Contains(searchString)
                                       || m.AspNetUser.MobilePhone.Contains(searchString)
                                       || m.AspNetUser.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
                                       || m.IdentificationNumber.Contains(searchString));
            }
        }
        else if (Command == "Reset")
        {

        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "lastname_desc":
                members = members.OrderByDescending(m => m.AspNetUser.LastName);
                break;
            case "firstname":
                members = members.OrderBy(m => m.AspNetUser.FirstName);
                break;
            case "firstname_desc":
                members = members.OrderByDescending(m => m.AspNetUser.FirstName);
                break;
            default:
                members = members.OrderBy(m => m.AspNetUser.LastName);
                break;
        }

        return View(members.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Are you evaluating your query? After your `OrderBy`, add `ToList()` to make sure

Comment: Updated my question with the full method.. :)

Comment: If you debug it, then put in the watch window `members.First().AspNetUser.LastName`, then possibly try a few others in the watch window such as `members.ElementAt(2).AspNetUser.LastName`, are any of them populated? Are they ordered in your watch window?

Comment: Let me give that a try..

Comment: Thanks for making me do this. I had an underlying issue with my ViewBag.  I've decided to remove this viewbag and use defined model instead and have now got things working using the above code.  Thank you for giving me a prod!

Comment: No worries, 99% of the time it's a good idea to not use the `ViewBag` as your model :)